# CSS Gradient doesn't appear

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm working on a project in which i have to apply a linear gradient to a page body.
The gradient just doesn't appear on the page.

I first thought the problem was an error in my code (although no syntax error were detected by the browser), but it didn't work neither with a code example from documentation or gradient generator.
Here is my CSS code now (provided by a generator) :

```
body
{
    background: #c5deea; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%, #8abbd7 31%, #066dab 100%); /* FF3.6+ */ 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c5deea), color-stop(31%,#8abbd7), color-stop(100%,#066dab)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */ 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c5deea', endColorstr='#066dab',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

And ... the body background is juste invisible. The problem does not come from the html code, since when I change the CSS by something like :

```
body
{
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

or with a background image it works ...
Of course i tried on different machines, with different browsers from latest to old but none worked.
I really don't know what's happening but it makes me insane : everything works except gradients and the error console does not show any errors ; i think i've tried anything i knew, but i'm still stuck. Thanks for helping.

EDIT :

Here is the full code :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 15px/1.5 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #4E443C;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);

    background: #c5deea; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%, #8abbd7 31%, #066dab 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c5deea), color-stop(31%,#8abbd7), color-stop(100%,#066dab)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c5deea', endColorstr='#066dab',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

How it appears in firefox 25.0.1 :

[image: ff]

EDIT 2 :

In Firebug, i've got this :

[image: firebug]

Which means the gradient is computed by the browser ... but is obvisouly not rendered ...

Comment: you will never get an error in web development

Comment: Its working http://jsfiddle.net/kpAFL/ - @ibi0tux

Comment: do you have any other css stylesheets attached to this?. If you can provide a link to the website, it will be good.

Comment: Sorry, the website is not online yet, and there is no other stylesheet

Comment: Check the firebug and see if you are over-riding the body style. Also can u post how your css style to body is being rendered in, say Firefox

Comment: I've edited my code, adding full source and screenshot.

Comment: background: #c5deea; /* Old browsers */

http://www.colorhexa.com/c5deea

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed setting a gradient on the body if it has a `margin` of 0 doesn't work.

```
body
{
    margin:0;
    background:linear-gradient(45deg,red,blue);
}
```

But, setting `height:100%` on html makes it render properly. Hope it helps.

```
html
{
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: 3 years and 2 months later ... fortunately I am not stuck on this anymore but thank you for your answer ! :D

Comment: haha yeah, i noticed the age of the post AFTER answering, but figured someone else might need it anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the code you provided is working, as @NathanLee said.
The problem however is with your browser. So make sure that your browser supports gradients

Comment: I tried under Firefox 25, Firefox 3.6 (old syntax) and Safari, without success ... i don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen to me. It seemed I also had a gradient on the background.

```
html
{
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(36, 36, 36), rgb(82, 82, 82));
}
```

It seems having both this gradient and a button gradient means the button loses. I' still trying to figure out how to fix it so both behave.